# Why is my background picture being pushed down when I add margin-auto?

Tags: html, css

I have a background picture, I'm trying to get the login form down the page by putting the margin auto but it drags down the image as well.

Here is my code:

```css
.container {
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  height:110vh;
 
}
.login-form {
  width: 500px;
  padding: 32px;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19), 0 6px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23);
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin-top:3%;
  margin-bottom:auto;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
}
```

```html
<div className="container" style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${cancer})` }}>
  {isLoading ? <div>loggin you in!</div> : null}
  <form onSubmit={onSubmit} className="login-form">
    <div>
      <em>
        <div>{formErrors.username}</div>
        <div>{formErrors.password}</div>
      </em>
    </div>
    <label>
      Username:
      <input type="text" value={credentials.username} onChange={onChange} name="username" id="name-input"
        placeholder="Username" />
    </label>
    <label>
      Password:
      <input type="password" value={credentials.password} onChange={onChange} name="password" id="password-input"
        placeholder="password" />
    </label>
    <div className="login-button-container">
      <button className="login-button" disabled={disabled}>
        Login
      </button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Not a fix but please note that the [<input>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-input-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.

Comment: you did not supply enough code but try using padding instead of margin.

Comment: @burkay that didn't work

Comment: Please edit your question. Use the snippet tool (<> icon on the toolbar) and add enough code to show your problem.